# How to input current date directly from datetime to pgfgantt

Tags: datetime, pgfgantt

I would like to input the current date taken from "datetime" into the "pgfgantt" package to update the date bar automatically at compilation.

The date seems to be in the correct format, 
however when input to pgfgantt, it throws an error:

```
! Use of \\ganttchart doesn't match its definition.
\new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.23 ]{2014-06-01}{2014-07-30}
```

Working code is here (replace "today=2014-06-02" with "today=\dashdate\today" to reproduce error):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newdateformat{dashdate}{\THEYEAR-\twodigit{\THEMONTH}-\twodigit{\THEDAY}}
%\dashdate\today

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}

\begin{ganttchart}[x unit=.3cm, hgrid,vgrid={dotted},time slot format=isodate,
today=
2014-06-02, %replace "2014-06-02" with "\dashdate\today" to reproduce error
today offset=.5,
today label=Current Date,
today label node/.append style={anchor=north west},
today label font=\itshape\color{red},today rule/.style={draw=blue, ultra thick}
]{2014-06-01}{2014-07-30}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name, week} \\
\ganttbar{Task-1.1}{2014-06-01}{2014-06-03} \\
\ganttbar{Task-1.2}{2014-06-03}{2014-06-06} \\
\ganttmilestone{Milestone 1}{2014-06-06} 

\end{ganttchart}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: Hm, I get: `ERROR: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfgantt/time slot format' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Comment: Use `today=\the\year-\the\month-\the\day,`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `today=\the\year-\the\month-\the\day`.